# How do i create a new VF page for Salesforce Analytics API

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting, analytics-api

We are novice to VisualForce Page and Apex development. Trying to create a new VF page using sandbox org. Also in that, we need to use jquery ajax callout.

We are trying to implement SFDC Analytics API :
[Salesforce-analytics-api-demo-code](https://th3silverlining.com/2013/11/10/salesforce-analytics-api-demo-code)

Any help on it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/09/using-the-salesforce-analytics-api-on-a-visualforce-page.html) tutorial from [Pat Patterson](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) (aka MetaDaddy, ex-Salesforce Developer Evangelist - Boy, do we miss him :() is a good starting point for how you can use Salesforce Analytics API on a VF page.

The key is to is to first fetch the `reportId` as shown below

```
// When the DOM is ready...
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Pass in the report ID like so:
    // https://c.prerelna1.visual.pre.force.com/apex/AnalyticsDemo?reportId=00Ox0000000fX7XEAU
    var reportId = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.reportId}';
```

Initialise ForceTK (this is a wrapper for doing CRUD operations on Salesforce) as follows

```
if (reportId) {
    // Get an instance of the REST API client and set the session ID
    var client = new forcetk.Client();
    client.setSessionToken('{!$Api.Session_ID}');

    // We'll keep the report data around for the life of the page
    var report = null;
```

The `report` variable will hold your report data. Then call the Analytics API endpoint

```
client.ajax("/v29.0/analytics/reports/"+reportId+"?includeDetails=true", function(response){
```

This will give you the data returned from the Analytics API. You can then render it on VF page like any other data and in any format e.g. table view/ chart etc.. Refer to the provided link for more details.